# Where is texless?

Tags: texlive

Yesterday I installed TeXlive 2014. I was using 2011 version.

Well, `texless` does not work. Terminal shows `texless: command not found`.

How to install `texless`? Or is there a new way to quickly view `cls` files, for example?

Comment: There has never been such a command. You can define a shell function (Bash) or alias (Tcsh) for it. But you can do `texdoc imakeidx.sty` for looking into a package, but it works only with package known to `texdoc`, not for `.cls` files.

Comment: So probably I found here a long time ago some hint to do that since I use it on my laptop.

Comment: Yes, `texdoc` I know. It works.

Comment: @egreg, now you told that it is an alias I googled and found http://www.stackprinter.com/export?service=tex.stackexchange&question=94638&printer=false&linktohome=true I asked it before. lol thanks. I'll close the post.

Comment: `function texless () { less $(kpsewhich $@) ; }` is much easier on a Unix bash shell.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't want `\textless`

Comment: @Herbert, yes. I'm talking about the shell function as egreg wrote.